Integer wrapping problem in kfifo.c in Linux kernel
I am studying the implementation of kfifo.c in Linux kernel version 2.6. I don't quite understand how the queue in and out pointers wrap around to handle the remainder.
For example, kfifo.c use l = fifo->in - fifo->out to calculate the space used in the queue. Suppose in = 0, out = 1, fifo->size = 8. And both in and out are unsigned int, both are 32 bits. So l = fifo->in - fifo->out will be 32 bits 1 represents 4294967295. But the actual used space in queue is l = (fifo->in - fifo->out) & (fifo->size-1) = 7
So my problem is Why l doesn't AND with the fifo->size-1?
unsigned int __kfifo_out_peek(struct __kfifo *fifo,
        void *buf, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int l;

    l = fifo->in - fifo->out;
    if (len > l)
        len = l;

    kfifo_copy_out(fifo, buf, len, fifo->out);
    return len;
}

static void kfifo_copy_out(struct __kfifo *fifo, void *dst,
        unsigned int len, unsigned int off)
{
    unsigned int size = fifo->mask + 1;
    unsigned int esize = fifo->esize;
    unsigned int l;

    off &= fifo->mask;
    if (esize != 1) {
        off *= esize;
        size *= esize;
        len *= esize;
    }
    l = min(len, size - off);

    memcpy(dst, fifo->data + off, l);
    memcpy(dst + l, fifo->data, len - l);
    /*
     * make sure that the data is copied before
     * incrementing the fifo->out index counter
     */
    smp_wmb();
}

Also, I have another question is the implementation of kfifo_unused in kfifo.c. fifo->mask+1 represents fifo->size. Also assuming in = 0, out = 1, fifo->size = 8. The following code will return 9, But actually the usused space should be 1.
static inline unsigned int kfifo_unused(struct __kfifo *fifo)
{
    return (fifo->mask + 1) - (fifo->in - fifo->out);
}

